# Articles with food

Tags: articles, food

> On Sundays he makes pizza. Sometime he fries chicken or fixes Chinese food. My mother watches and helps. She cuts the vegetables and tosses the salad.

Please explain why there is no article before *pizza* and *chicken*, as both nouns are common singular and general. Also, please explain, why the article *the* is used before *vegetables* and *salad*. *Vegetables* is a common plural noun and *salad* is a common singular noun.

Comment: You don't need articles before vegetables or salad. And you could have an article before *pizza, chicken,* and *Chinese food.* The difference is stylistic,not grammatical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are frozen pizzas countable or uncountable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121767/are-frozen-pizzas-countable-or-uncountable)

Answer (score 14):

> On Sundays he makes pizza.

This could be *he makes pizzas* (count noun) or *he makes pizza* (mass noun) - both are in use. *He makes a pizza* is possible, but would imply that he only ever makes one pizza.

> Sometimes he fries chicken ...

Exactly the same as "pizza": "chickens" or "a chicken" would both be possible; except that when you refer to chickens as count nouns ("chickens" or "a chicken") it tends to mean whole chickens, rather than just some chicken-meat.

> ... or Chinese food.

"Food" is always a mass noun (except, like many mass nouns, when it means "kinds of food").

In all the above, you have not yet introduced the food in question to the discourse, so "the" is not appropriate.

But

> She cuts the vegetables. She tosses the salad.

Even though the vegetables and the salad have not yet been explicitly mentioned, the prior reference to the pizza or chicken has brought the meal into the discourse, so "the" may be used to refer to parts of the meal. It would also be possible to use indefinite articles here:

> She cuts vegetables and tosses a salad.

Comment: My concept of differentiating between count and mass noun is either we can put numbers behind the noun or not like pizza can be 1, 2, 3 and chicken can be 1,2,3..... Did you mean that If  we do not use any article before any countable noun then it means we consider that this noun is a mass noun...e.g. Mitchell is a nice girl but it can be written as  Mitchell is nice girl.

Comment: No, You  can't make just _any_ noun a mass noun, but there are many which can. Words which denote a substance are usually mass nouns: this includes kinds of meat - "We had beef, chicken, and lamb". In some of those cases the word is also used for the animal, in which case it is a count noun: "There were chickens and lambs in the farmyard". Some other kinds of foods can also be treated as quasi-substances, and massified: "There was pizza followed by cake", but others can't: I don't think you would hear "We had biscuit/cookie", for example. There aren't rules for this.

Answer (score 5):

In the examples you give, the items are not specific items, but general cases.

If it is Sunday, he makes a pizza, because on Sundays he makes pizza. After he makes the pizza, he will eat it.

Comment: brendinger sorry iam unable to get your point. What you mean specifically.